# functions with an indefinite number of parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

I want realize code like this:

```
template <typename... Args>
class A
{
public:
    A(Args... args) {ind = std::make_tuple(args...);}
    std::tuple<Args...> ind;
};

void foo()
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
void foo(First _first, Rest... _rest)
{
    std::cout << _first;
    foo(_rest...);
}


int main()
{
    A<int, int> a1(1, 2);
    A<int, int, int> a2(1, 2, 3);
    A<int, int, int, int> a3(1, 2, 3, 4);

    foo(a1.ind);
    foo(a2.ind);
    foo(a3.ind);
}
```

In Class A the field ind does not have to be tuple, the main thing is that the foo method accepts a set of parameters.

Comment: "the main thing is that the function is passed pack of parameters." Sorry, I can't understand this sentence. Can clarify please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "unpack" the parameters from the tuple before you call it.

maybe something like that:

```
template< size_t ... Ints >
class integer_sequence{};


template < typename T, size_t N >
struct add_sequence;

template < size_t N, size_t ... IDX >
struct add_sequence< integer_sequence<IDX...>, N>
{
    using type = integer_sequence< IDX..., N>;
};

template < size_t N >
struct sequence_helper
{
    using type = typename add_sequence< typename sequence_helper<N-1>::type, N-1>::type;
};

template<>
struct sequence_helper<0>
{
    using type = integer_sequence<>;
};

template<size_t N>
using make_integer_sequence = typename sequence_helper<N>::type;

template < typename IS, typename TUPLE >
struct call;

template < size_t ... IDX, typename ... PARMS >
struct call< integer_sequence< IDX...>, std::tuple< PARMS...>>
{
    static void go( std::tuple< PARMS...> parms )
    {
        foo( std::get< IDX >( parms ) ... );
    }
};

template < typename ... PARMS >
void foo2( std::tuple< PARMS...>& tup )
{
    call<make_integer_sequence< sizeof...(PARMS)>, std::tuple< PARMS...>>::go( tup );
}


int main()
{
    A<int, int> a1(1, 2);
    A<int, int, int> a2(1, 2, 3);
    A<int, int, int, int> a3(1, 2, 3, 4);

    foo2(a1.ind);
    foo2(a2.ind);
    foo2(a3.ind);
}
```

Most of the code here is available in C++14 or C++17 without writing it your self. We have the 2020 and you should think about changing to C++17! It makes not much sense to stay with outdated compilers and write all the code again and again.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I can't use C++14 or C++17.